# Best first anime for anime newbie?

Tags: discussion

I have a friend who I feel would love anime if he would give it a chance. He lets some of the common misconceptions and stereotypes of anime keep him from watching some fantastic works of entertainment.

I want to introduce anime to him, but I will probably only be able to convince him to watch one show, due to his current lack of interest.

What show should I use to showcase anime in its glory to my friend? I want something that's interesting on multiple levels (violent but also mentally stimulating, etc.). Unfortunately, it probably has to be dubbed in English (eventually he'll get to the good stuff). Does anyone have any recommendatons? My current ideas were Attack on Titan, Steins;Gate, etc.

Comment: [take a look at this](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/you-want-recommendations-heres-a-list-of-them)

Comment: If you really want your friend to get into anime, you'll have to gauge their interest in different genres first. "Most popular" anime doesn't mean "liked by everybody". I know a few people who only watch one or two works of all the anime (like Mushishi) and there's no convincing them to watch anything else. Good luck and don't despair or blame your friend if it doesn't work out as you wanted.

Comment: @Hakase I saw that list of recommendations, but I feel that is for more seasoned anime watchers. For example, I don't think that the Monogatari series is a good show for a newbie to anime to watch (this is subjective, I know). I was more looking for recommendations that other people have had experience successfully opening the 'anime door' to previously uninterested people.

Comment: The problem is it heavily depends on each person. You could ask people who have introduced their friends to anime when there were not many good introduction level works, and the choice would be narrow enough. But now there are many more good works to choose from and the potential for success is greater thanks to that. So I suggest, as a seasoned viewer, to consider each genre and your friend's favorite shows, compare and present them with some choice. Don't forget different art styles, as (in my experience) people sometimes really dislike certain styles. And try to avoid 42457637-episode ones.

Comment: Like @Hakase said, it depends on each person. As for me, I watched Sora no Otoshimono at first, ( I know it's not the best anime, but hey, it pique my interest at first )  I came on my friend's house when he was watching it. And then I watch Angel Beats, just because there's Angel on title and as you might know, Sora no Otoshimono is about angeloid. This is the first time I really got attached to anime, after that a friends of mine recommend The World God Only Knows, and that deal the rest. I've watched hundreds of title and the number still keep going :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Hakase](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users/191/hakase) already mentions, it would be best to first gauge their interests

It also won't hurt to keep in mind, that if your friend(s) haven't been exposed to anime before, or maybe even exposed to the 'Otaku' culture, it would probably be best to stick to anime's that follow a bit more of a traditional western style. Keeping little to no fan-service would probably be a smart move as well towards a newcomer.

Keeping the before mentioned in mind. Some recommendations would be

- [Baccano!](http://myanimelist.net/anime/2251/Baccano)
- [Cowboy Bebop](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1/Cowboy_Bebop)
- [Gunslinger Girl](http://myanimelist.net/anime/134/Gunslinger_Girl)
- [Black Lagoon](http://myanimelist.net/anime/889/Black_Lagoon)