# Creating a list of recommendation resources

Tags: discussion

We have [this post here on meta](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/you-want-recommendations-heres-a-list-of-them) where we put our own recommendations for all to see. It's a nice small list but it's not really much for an avid viewer. When we get questions [like this](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3880/best-first-anime-for-anime-newbie), they're usually closed because [we don't answer them](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117/should-we-allow-recommendation-questions), but I thought we could at least point people in the right direction.

So in this post I ask you to add the sites which may be useful in getting recommendations to this question's body: [You want recommendations? Here's a list of them](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/you-want-recommendations-heres-a-list-of-them) under the "Third-party links" section.

Answer (score 2):

I have an answer on the main site that may be of interest:

https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/7341/1530 "Are there any anime suggestion engines?"

Comment: added to the post